# Phonegap push notification with parse.com

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform, cordova-plugins

Im looking for a way to implement push notification on a phonegap application using javascript and parse.com. I found this turorial for iOS
 http://www.ladeezfirstmedia.com/2013/08/01/tutorial-part-5-push-it-real-good-with-push-notifications-using-corona-sdk-and-parse-com/
, which seems pretty straight forward, and this tutorial for android http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/10/10/PhoneGap-Parsecom-and-Push-Notifications.

However, Im using cordova 3.3. and rather stay away from editing the AndroidManifest, which I need to do in the last tutorial. Can any one point me in the right direction, maybe to a tutorial where I can use cordova plugin and easily combine it with parse.com by using javascript for both iO and Android? Btw Im building my project locally in the terminal.

What I want is to notify the user, when its their turn in a game.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer I've just posted, I've just got the Android Parse PNs working:

[How do I get Parse.com Push Notifications working in a Cordova/Phonegap Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038694/how-do-i-get-parse-com-push-notifications-working-in-a-cordova-phonegap-android/25038695#25038695)

It does require  you to modify the AndroidManifest and some of the Java files as well, but not a lot. I can't find a plugin that works without doing some of the work myself.

You can use the plugin for iOS as well, you don't need to edit any of the iOS source code but will need to generate a certificate for iOS push notifications, as documented on Parse.

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications