# Parse push notification not appearing as System Tray notification on Android (Cordova app)

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a cordova based Android app. I have added the `PushPlugin` (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to register the device with GCM and also get notified when a push notification comes in.

I am not using the parse Android SDK. I am sending a push notification using the parse.com service.

When the app is running in the foreground the callback registered in my code is called properly with the data in the push. However when the app is suspended or stopped no notification appears in the system tray and there is no beep or vibration either. However I do see log lines for an incoming push in `adb logcat`.

Instead if I send a push notification using GCM directly, when the app is suspended/stopped, I get a proper system tray notification with my app icon, the specified title. There a audio alert and also vibration.

What's different with the push sent from Parse.com that makes it not appear in the system tray? And how can I make `adb logcat` print more information about the push payload itself?

Comment: I had that problem, but at the end I used another plugin See this answer to resolve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25038695/974844

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Parse.com Push Notifications working in a Cordova/Phonegap Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038694/how-do-i-get-parse-com-push-notifications-working-in-a-cordova-phonegap-android)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Probably a duplicate. Nevertheless the solution that I eventually came up with is somewhat less complex. The problem seemed to be because of the way Parse formats the JSON payload sent in the Push. I forked the PushPlugin repo and added code to handle the Push payload format. https://github.com/brahmana/PushPlugin

Comment: @brahmana Glad you got it working. You should post your solution below and provide some details please. There is not enough good info on how to get this working at the moment. I ended up forking my own version of such a [Parse Push Handler for Cordova](https://github.com/mobiRic/cordova-plugin-parse-pushhandler).